# Java switch statement completely skipped

Tags: java, android, switch-statement, android-resources, typed-arrays

I am trying a switch statement to dynamically determine which part of an actionbar dropdown spinner is being selected. This switch statement does not even go to my `default` case, what am I doing wrong?

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //restart fragment with selected spinner item's api call
    TypedArray mArray = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.spinner_actionbar);
    switch(mArray.getResourceId(itemPosition, 0)){
    case R.string.spinner_timeline:
        break;
    case R.string.spinner_profile:
        break;
    case R.string.spinner_top_posts:
        break;
    case 0:
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    mArray.recycle();
    return false;
}
```

`mArray.getResourceId(itemPosition, 0)` returns the position of an arraylist OR 0, and none of my cases not even case 0 is being called

Thanks for any insight, this is using the android framework

Comment: How do you know (or how have you proved) that none of your cases are executing?

Comment: You're just breaking out of every condition without doing anything else.

Comment: Why, why, why do people leave in // TODO Auto-generated method stub

Comment: @DavidConrad shouldn't bother you that much. Debug then clean up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have empty cases in your `switch-case` block. You want to do something inside each `case`, besides just `break` out of the block. For example:

```
case R.string.spinner_timeline:
    System.out.println(R.string.spinner_timeline);
    break;
case R.string.spinner_profile:
    System.out.println(R.string.spinner_profile);
    break;
case R.string.spinner_top_posts:
    System.out.println(R.string.spinner_top_posts);
    break;
case 0:
    break;
default:
    System.out.println("default case...");
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

two cases might be triggered by your code:

case 0 and default

both of those are break so yo cannot tell which is triggered.

R.ids are not position ids most likely

Answer (score 0):

Here, the `switch` statement is used without making use of why and when to use the `switch` statement.

A switch statement is useful when you need to select one of several alternatives based on the value of an integer, a character, or a String variable. The basic form of the switch statement is this:

```
switch (expression)
{ 
  case constant:
        statements;
        break;
  [ case constant-2:
        statements;
        break;  ] ...
  [ default:
        statements;
        break;  ] ...
}
```

In your case, you are using the switch and not telling what to do when you enter the switch-case. As soon as you enter, you leave from the case using the break statement. You are doing the same thing in default case also.

Reference links that you should go through:

Java Switch-case

http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/switch-statements-in-java.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html